# Show that uniform continuity implies stochastic equicontinuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $\Theta$ be a metric space and assume it is compact. Let $W_t: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a random variable for $t\leq T$. Let $m(.,\theta): \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^s$. Let $\mathcal{M}:=\{m(.,\theta) \text{ s.t. } \theta \in \Theta \}$ be a class of functions from $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $\mathbb{R}^s$ indexed by $\theta \in \Theta$.

Consider the empirical process indexed by $\theta$, $v_T(.)=\{v_T(\theta ), \theta \in \Theta \}$, where 
$$
v_T(\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}} \sum_{t=1}^{T}[m(W_t,\theta)-E(m(W_t,\theta))]
$$

Assume that $v_T(\theta)$ is continuous in each point $\theta \in \Theta$. I think, by compactness of $\Theta$, this implies $v_T(\theta)$ uniformly continuous in $\theta$.

Consider the sequence of empirical processes $\{v_T(.) \text{ s.t. } T\geq 1 \}$. Does uniform continuity of $v_T(\theta)$ in $\theta$ $\forall T$ imply stochastic equicontinuity of $\{v_T(.) \text{ s.t. } T\geq 1 \}$?  How can I show it?